# Locally integrable distributions

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Is it possible that a locally integrable function which doesn't belong to any $\mathbb{L}^p$ space ($p\in [1,\infty]$) define a tempered distribution on the Schwartz space ?

Comment: Sure, $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: Nice and clear. So basically the integral is a tempered distribution. Thx

Comment: @Jacky ChongAhah no wait, $1_\mathbb{R}$ is in $\mathbb{L}^\infty$

Comment: every locally integrable function defines a distribution, and it is tempered whenever $\int_{-x}^x |f(t)|dt = o(x^k)$ for some $k$

Comment: do you know how to prove $f(x) = 1$ is a tempered distribution? and $f(x) = x^2$ ?

Comment: @user1952009         I can prove $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{R}$ is a tempered distribution but $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{R} \in \mathbb{L}^\infty$ so that's no good for my question. I think your second example is : let me try.
$\lvert \int \varphi(x) x^2 \text{d}x \rvert = \lvert \int \frac{\varphi(x)x^2(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\text{d}x \rvert \leq 2 \max_{\alpha+\beta \leq 4} \lvert \lvert x^\alpha \partial^\beta \varphi(x) \rvert \rvert_\infty $. Is this the way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, if you are not sure write all the steps. What about a general $f \in L^1_{loc}$, $\int_{-x}^x |f(t)|dt < C x^k$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int_{-x}^x |f(t)|dt < C_1 |x|^k$ then $\varphi \mapsto \langle f, \varphi \rangle$ is a tempered distribution :

$$\int_{0}^A f(x) \varphi(x)dx = \varphi(A)\int_{0}^A f(t)dt-\int_{0}^A \left(\int_0^x f(t)dt\right) \varphi'(x)dx$$
with $\varphi \in S(\mathbb{R})$ : $\ \lim_{|A| \to \infty}\varphi(A)\int_{0}^A f(t)dt= 0$ so that
$$\langle f,\varphi \rangle = \lim_{A \to \infty} \int_{0}^A f(x) \varphi(x)dx-\int_{0}^{-A} f(x) \varphi(x)dx =  -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_0^x f(t)dt\right) \varphi'(x)dx$$
And $$|\varphi'(x) (1+|x|^k)(1+x^2)| \le \sup_t |\varphi'(t)| (1+|t|^k)(1+t^2)$$
$$\le \|\varphi'\|_\infty+\|x^2\varphi'\|_\infty+\|x^k\varphi'\|_\infty+\|x^{k+2}\varphi'\|_\infty$$
i.e.
$$|\langle f, \varphi \rangle| \le \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_0^x |f(t)|dt \right) |\varphi'(x)|dx \le \int_{-\infty}^\infty C_1 |x|^k \frac{|\varphi'(x)| (1+|x|^k)(1+x^2)}{(1+|x|^k)(1+x^2)}dx$$
$$ \le \int_{-\infty}^\infty C_1  \frac{\|\varphi'\|_\infty+\|x^2\varphi'\|_\infty+\|x^k\varphi'\|_\infty+\|x^{k+2}\varphi'\|_\infty }{1+x^2}dx \le \pi C_1 \sum_{\alpha+\beta \le k+3}\|x^\alpha\varphi^{(\beta)}\|_\infty$$

Showing the continuity of $\varphi \mapsto \langle f, \varphi \rangle$ in the Schwartz topology.