# [Residue Theorem]: explicit calculus of an integral along the real axis.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, residue-calculus

I'm asked to find the explicit form of $(eq.1)$. My first attempt was an heuristic one, given by knowing few basic properties of fourier transform and a remarkable transform (see third column on the rule: 101/106 and 208 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms). Anyway, it gives the following chain of equalities: $(eq.2)$. This result is correct (i have the final solutions of exercises by the book). Furthermore, it suggest me that every functions like the one in $(eq.3)$ can be evaluate using the same method. However i cannot use those remarkable results and i should solve the problem using explicitely the definition, that is solving explicitely something like the integral in $(eq.4)$. Notice that i have changed the function to integrate since i believe that the original function is part of a more general class that can still be analyzed in similar manner. **At this point i got stuck, untill i found the residue theorem**. In particular, i found this good example from wikipedia that i was trying to adapt to my situation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#An_integral_along_the_real_axis). Then i followed the same steps (integration along the two semicircles enclosing each of the poles: $\pm \, ia$, and the calculation of the respective residues). But in my case i can't really understand the following:

1. At some point i get the expression in $(eq.5)$. Now, the claim is that the last integral should be null, but i managed to show that the estimation done by wikipedia holds only for $(\beta =0)$.. it is not the case! **Is there a way to demonstrate that this integral goes to zero?**
2. In the case of $(\beta =1)$ i did the desperate act to suppose that the last integral is (indeed) zero.. so i get the result in $(eq.6)$, where the module shows up from evaluating both the cases: $(x\gt0, \; x\lt0)$. From this point ahead i can continue, obtaining the result in $(eq.7)$. We can see that the result itself is good, but there isn't signum function like there was in the $(eq.2)$.. and it should be there.. **how could the signum function appear following that method?**

---

$$\mathcal{F^{-1}}\left[-\frac{ik}{\sqrt{2\pi}\text{  }(k^2+4)} \right] \qquad (1)$$

---

$$\mathcal{F^{-1}}\left[-\frac{ik}{\sqrt{2\pi}\text{  }(k^2+4)} \right] = -\frac{1}{4}  \mathcal{F^{-1}}\left[\frac{4(ik)}{\sqrt{2\pi}\text{  }(k^2+4)} \right] \\[6ex]
\text{where:} \quad \left[ \frac{4(ik)}{\sqrt{2\pi}\text{  }(k^2+4)} \right] = \mathcal{F} \left[ \frac{d}{dx}\text{  }e^{-2|x|} \right] = (ik)\text{  } \mathcal{F} \left[e^{-2|x|} \right] \\[6ex] \text{and then:} \quad \mathcal{F^{-1}}\left[-\frac{ik}{\sqrt{2\pi}\text{  }(k^2+4)} \right] = -\frac{1}{4}\text{  } \mathcal{F^{-1}} \left(\mathcal{F} \left[ \frac{d}{dx}\text{  }e^{-2|x|} \right]\right) = \\[6ex]
= -\frac{1}{4}\text{  }\left[ \frac{1}{4}\text{  }e^{-2|x|} \right] = \frac{1}{2}\text{  }\operatorname{sgn}(x)\text{  }e^{-2|x|}\qquad (2)$$

---

$$f(k) = \frac{(ik)^\beta}{k^2 + a^2} \quad \text{where} \; \beta \in \mathbb{N}, \; \text{and} \; a \in \mathbb{R^+} \qquad (3)$$

---

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(ik)^\beta}{k^2 + a^2} \text{  } e^{ikx} \text{  } dk \qquad (4)$$

---

$$\int_{\operatorname{straight}} \frac{(ik)^\beta \text{ }e^{ikx}}{k^2 + a^2}\text{  }dk = 2\pi i \left[\operatorname{Res}_{z=ia}\right] - \int_{arc} \frac{(ik)^\beta \text{ }e^{ikx}}{k^2 + a^2}\text{  }dk \quad \text{where} \; \left[\operatorname{Res}_{z=ia}\right]=\frac{1}{2}ie^{-ax} \qquad (5)$$

---

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{ik}{k^2 + a^2} \text{  } e^{ikx} \text{  } dk = 2\pi i \left( \frac{1}{2}\text{ }i\text{ }e^{-a|x|} \right)=-\pi\text{ }e^{-a|x|} \qquad (6)$$

---

$$ \mathcal{F^{-1}}\left[-\frac{ik}{\sqrt{2\pi}\text{  }(k^2+4)} \right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} -\frac{ik}{\sqrt{2\pi}\text{  }(k^2+4)} e^{ikx}\text{  }dk \\[6ex]  
= -\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(ik)\text{  }e^{ikx}}{k^2+4}\text{  }dk = \frac{1}{2}\text{  }e^{-2|x|} \qquad (7)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_\beta(k) =\frac{(ik)^\beta}{k^2+a^2}$, where $\beta\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a>0$.  For $\beta=0$, $f\in L^1$ and has Fourier Transform given by

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f_0\}(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_0(k) e^{ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2+a^2} \,e^{ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=\pi\frac{e^{-|ax|}}{|a|}
\end{align}$$

For $\beta >0$, $f_\beta(k)$ is locally integrable and yields a tempered distribution $\left(f_\beta\right)_{D}=\left(\frac{(ik)^\beta}{k^2+a^2}\right)_{D}$ such that for any $\phi \in \mathbb{S}$ (i.e., $\phi$ is a Schwarz Space function)

$$\begin{align}
\langle \left(f_\beta\right)_{D},\phi\rangle&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(ik)^\beta}{k^2+\beta^2} \phi(k)\,dk\tag1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that for $\beta>0$

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{f_\beta\},\phi\rangle&=\langle f_\beta, \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle \\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(ik)^\beta}{k^2+a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)e^{ikx}\,dx\,dk\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2+a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\frac{d^\beta}{dx^\beta}e^{ikx}\,dx\,dk\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^\beta}{k^2+a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi^{(\beta)}(x)e^{ikx}\,dx\,dk\\\\
&=(-1)^\beta \frac{\pi}{|a|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi^{(\beta)}(x)e^{-|ax|}\,dx\\\\
&=(-1)^\beta \frac{\pi}{|a|} \langle \phi^{(\beta)},\psi_a \rangle \\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{|a|} \langle \phi,\psi_a^{(\beta)} \rangle \\\\
\end{align}$$

where $\psi_a$ is the distribution $\psi_a(x)=\left(e^{-|ax|}\right)_D$ and $\psi^{(\beta)}$ is the $\beta^{th}$ order distributional derivative of $\psi_a$.

Finally, we conclude that the Fourier transform of $f_\beta$ is given by the distribution

$$\mathscr{F}\{f_\beta\}(x)=\frac\pi{|a|}\frac{d^\beta}{dx^\beta}\left(e^{-|ax|}\right)_D$$

For $\beta=1$, we have

$$\mathscr{F}\{f_1\}(x)=-\pi e^{-|ax|}\text{sgn}(x)$$

For $\beta=2$, we have

$$\mathscr{F}\{f_2\}(x)=\pi |a|e^{-|ax|}-2\pi \delta(x)$$

Comment: Hi Mark! I'm glad to see a your answer! But, can we discuss about?

Comment: First of all: can we say $\left[\mathscr{F}\{f_0\}(x) = \pi\frac{e^{-|ax|}}{|a|}\right]$ using the residue theorem as wikipedia did? (i really want to have a safe method to calculate it explicitely, instead of relying on the remind of remarkable results).

Comment: Why did you suggest that for $\beta>0$, $f_\beta(k)$ is a tempered distribuition? Is the locally integrability (integrable over every compact subset of the domain) a sufficient condition?

Comment: At this regard i found (from wikipedia): "Tempered distributions generalize the bounded (or slow-growing) locally integrable functions; all distributions with compact support and all square-integrable functions are tempered distributions. **More generally, all functions that are products of polynomials with elements of Lp space** $L^p(\mathbb{R^n})$ for $p\ge 1$ are tempered distributions". This last claim seems to do the job.. is that fair?

Comment: Then i already had experience of the property: $\langle \mathscr{F}\{f_\beta\},\phi\rangle =\langle f_\beta, \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle$ for shwartz functions, and first two step of integrations are fair as well.

Comment: But i can't really understand the passage: $\left[\phi(x)\frac{d^\beta}{dx^\beta}e^{ikx} \longrightarrow (-1)^\beta \text{  } \phi^{(\beta)}(x)e^{ikx}\right]$. And what $\phi^{(\beta)}$ means? The derivative of the function (it seems)?

Comment: In the following step, it seems you integrated first {$wrt \text{   } k$} leaving behind the integration {$wrt \text{   } x$}, even if $e^{ikx}$ is not separable under those variables. Is that legit?

Comment: **EDIT - IMPORTANT QUESTION:** trying to solve $\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2+a^2} \,e^{ikx}\,dk\right]$ with residue theorem like wikipedia did (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#An_integral_along_the_real_axis), i feel unconfortable with the result because the residues i calculated respectively for $(x\gt 0)$ and $(x\lt 0)$ are: $\left[\frac{e^{-ax}}{2ia} \right]$ and $\left[-\frac{e^{ax}}{2ia} \right]$. So, the final result of the integral should be: $\left[\frac{\pi}{a}\operatorname{sgn}(x)\text{  }e^{-a|x|} \right]$. **Why not?**

Comment: @giuliolib Well, that is a lot to address.  First, yes one can evaluate the Fourier transform of $f_0$ using the residue theorem.  For $a>0$ ($a<0$), close the contour in the upper (lower) half plane.

Comment: Yes, locally integrable functions are tempered distributions on $\mathbb{S}$ [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968086/locally-integrable-distributions).  But there are other tempered distributions.  The DIrac Delta is a tempered distribution.

Comment: Yes, the notation $\phi^{(\beta)}$ means the derivative of order $\beta$.  Integration by parts $\beta$ times results in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x) \frac{d^\beta}{dx^\beta}e^{ikx}\,dx=(-1)^\beta\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi^{(\beta)}(x) e^{ikx}\,dx$

Comment: In the "next step," I evaluated the outer integral using the residue theorem.  Alternatively, we can interchange the order of integration and use the result in evaluating the Fourier transform of $f_0$.

Comment: As explained earlier, in applying the residue theorem, we closed the contour in the lower half plane when $x<0$ (I wrote $a<0$ before; it is a typographical error.).  But the residue theorem requires the contour to be oriented counterclockwise.  So, the minus sign gets absorbed and there is no $\text{sgn}(x)$ in the result.

Comment: Thanks Mark for all your disponibility.. you should get awarded much more than a simple 'accepted answer'.. the last comment was relevatory, since i too discovered the dumb error i was committing.. just one last thing..

Comment: in $\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x) \frac{d^\beta}{dx^\beta}e^{ikx}\,dx=(-1)^\beta\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi^{(\beta)}(x) e^{ikx}\,dx \right]$ integration by part was a nice shoot, but could be related also to the property of tempered distribution: $\left[\langle \phi, \text{  } \partial^{\alpha}T \rangle = (-1)^{\alpha}\text{  }\langle T,\text{  }\partial^{\alpha}\phi \rangle \right]$?

Comment: Yes, that property of distribution is a definition and mirrors integration by parts when the distribution is an ordinary function.